# REACT - Unknown event handler property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a custom component called RepositoryListDialog, and when i use it

```
 <RepositoryListDialog  onselecteditem = {this.onRepositorySelected} />
```

React return me a waring in the console:

**Unknown event handler property `onselecteditem`. It will be ignored.**

I noticed that this problem figure out if i put an unrecognized property for a native DOM tag like div, or something else.

But RepositoryListDialog is a custom tag, and i don't understand this react warning.

#### RepositoryListDialog

```
<Dialog   
  aria-labelledby="repository-list-dialog" 
  open={this.props.dialogShowed} 
  classes={{paper:classes.cssRepositoryListDialogPaper}} 
  {...other}> 
  
  <DialogTitle id="repository-list-dialog-title">Select Repository</DialogTitle> 
</Dialog>
```

Comment: Could you post you RepositoryListDialog   code . Thanks

Comment: <Dialog 
                    aria-labelledby="repository-list-dialog" 
                    open={this.props.dialogShowed}
                    classes={{paper:classes.cssRepositoryListDialogPaper}} 
                    {...other}
                >
                    <DialogTitle id="repository-list-dialog-title">Select Repository</DialogTitle>

                </Dialog>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `RepositoryListDialog` component you might have something like this:

```
<div {...this.props}>
```

Comment: i have  <div {...other}>
i removed it and it's work.
Can you please explain me?

Comment: what does other object consist of?

Comment: if your `other` object include `onselecteditem` property, then you will get  `<div onselecteditem={other[onselecteditem]}>` in result

Comment: probably the other object contains a series of props which they are not recognized by the div element

Comment: Yes. I think so too

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this. Try capitalizing your first letter. JSX expects custom components to start with an uppercase. Seems to work either way (i.e. it warns but it still works), but capitalizing the leading letter should eliminate the issue.

Comment: Hey @AndrewS welcome to SO - try to include some code example of you what would actually change, and maybe some notes about what this answer does differently compared to the already accept one